# How to get ansible.module_utils to resolve my custom directory

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, ansible-2.x

Certain variables in ansible.cfg seem to not be taking affect.
Ansible 2.2.1.0
Python 2.7.10
Mac OS Version 10.12.5

We have created a custom class that will be used in our custom Ansible module. The class lives here:

> /sites/utils/local/ansible/agt_module_utils/ldapData.py
>   /sites/utils/local/ansible/agt_module_utils/**init**.py

The class inside ldapData.py is named:

class ldapDataClass(object):

In all cases, **init**.py is a zero byte file.
Our Ansible module is located here:

> /sites/utils/local/ansible/agt_modules/**init**.py
>   /sites/utils/local/ansible/agt_modules/agtWeblogic.py

The import statement in atgWeblogic looks as follows:

```
from ansible.module_utils.ldapData import ldapDataClass
```

I have also tried:

```
from ldapData import ldapDataClass
```

The config file has the following lines:

> library = /sites/utils/local/ansible/att_modules
>   module_utils = /sites/utils/local/ansible/att_module_utils

When running our module, the modules directory IS resolved but the module_utils directory is not resolved. When the include is "from ansible.module_utils.ldapData import ldapDataClass" the failure is before ansible even connects to the remote machine. When the include is "from ldapData import ldapDataClass" the failure is on the remote machine. Below I am showing the failure "on the remote machine" (scroll right to see full error):

> nverkland@local>ansible ecomtest37 -m agtWeblogic  -a "action=stop instances=tst37-shop-main" -vvv

```
ecomtest37 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_name": "agtWeblogic"
    }, 
    "module_stderr": "", 
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_FwHCmh/ansible_module_attWeblogic.py\", line 63, in <module>\r\n    from ldapData import ldapDataClass\r\nImportError: No module named ldapData\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
```

If I move the ldapData.py file into the "ansible installed" module_utils directory (/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/ on my Mac) the module runs fine. What have I done incorrectly in my config file that has prevented the use of my "custom" module_utils directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Konstantin's notes helped. I managed to solve the riddle. 
In my config file I had:

```
module_utils = /sites/utils/local/ansible/agt_module_utils
```

This causes Ansible to think that my class is found at:

```
import ansible.agt_module_utils.ldapData (working)
```

until now I was attempting to find the class at:

```
import ansible.module_utils.ldapData (broken)
```

Answer (score 7):

`module_utils` path is configurable since Ansible 2.3: [changelog](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/CHANGELOG.md#23-ramble-on---2017-04-12), [PR](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/20913/commits).

I guess you have to upgrade or refactor the module.

**Update**: working example

Project tree:

```
.
├── ansible
│   └── ansible.cfg
├── module_utils
│   └── mycommon.py
└── modules
    └── test_module.py
```

ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
library = ../modules
module_utils = ../module_utils
```

mycommon.py:

```
class MyCommonClass(object):

    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        return 'world'
```

test_module.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
from ansible.module_utils.mycommon import MyCommonClass

module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec = dict()
)
module.exit_json(changed=True, hello=MyCommonClass.hello())
```

Execution:

```
$ ansible localhost -m test_module
 [WARNING]: Host file not found: /etc/ansible/hosts

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": true,
    "hello": "world"
}
```

Ansible version:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.3.1.0
  config file = /<masked>/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'../modules']
  python version = 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]
```

Comment: I have now upgraded to ansible 2.3 and the results have not changed.

Comment: I have now upgraded to ansible 2.3 and the results have not changed.

library = /sites/utils/local/ansible/att_modules
module_utils = /sites/utils/local/ansible/att_module_utils

nverkland@local=>ls -1 /sites/utils/local/ansible/agt_module_utils
__init__.py
ldapData.py

ansible 2.3.0.0
  config file = /sites/utils/local/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/sites/utils/local/ansible/agt_modules/']
  python version = 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]

Comment: I've added working example. Please inspect your configuration.